# How can I require a specific combination of parameters (i.e. omit required alias names)?

Tags: typescript

I have a question regarding the omission of required parameters given the the satisfaction of an alias. I know this sounds needlessly complicated, so let me provide a practical use case.

If we take a quick look at the Bing Maps API - REST documentation under "Common Parameters and Types" (which can be found here: [Bing Maps - Common Parameters and Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/common-parameters-and-types/?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fbingmaps%2Frest-services%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2FBingMaps%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json))

If you give the documentation a quick glance, you may notice there are a few "aliased" parameter names.

For the sake of explanation, let's say we have a coordinates style object consisting of both a latitude and longitude. Both latitude and longitude have short aliases - respectively "lat" and "lng". How might we go about creating types that are smart enough to accept a combination of those required while omitting superfluous params that have previously been satisfied?

```
type Latitude  = { latitude: number }  | { lat: number };
type Longitude = { longitude: number } | { lng: number };
type Location  = Latitude & Longitude;

function formatLocation(loc: Location) {
    //... Do something useful
}

formatLocation({
    lat: 123.456,
    latitude: 123.456, // <--- would like for this to be an error or omitted as "lat" is already satisfied.
    longitude: -12.3456
});
```

I know there is a way to achieve such a behaviour with TypeScript "advanced types" (specifically exclude, extract, omit, among others) However, is there a way achieve this dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically" here?  Can you show an example of what does and does not count as dynamic?

Comment: Hi jcalz, and thank you for the reply. I'm sorry if I was unclear about my use of "dynamic" here. I simply mean that if we knew in advance which combination would be used (e.g. long latitude, alias lng OR alias latitude, alias longitude) we could simply omit the remaining values by creating a new type like 

type current = Omit<Latitude, "lat"> 

is there a way to achieve this on fly? Ergo, dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

My inclination here would be to make a type function called `OmitSuperfluousProperties<T>` which would take a union type `T` and produce a new union where each member explicitly forbids extra keys from the other members.  So `OmitSuperfluousProperties<{a: string} | {b: number}>` should become something like `{a: string, b?: never} | {a?: never, b: number}`.

Here's one possible definition:

```
type OmitSuperfluousProperties<T, K extends PropertyKey = AllKeys<T>> =
    T extends any ? (
        T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>>
    ) extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never
    : never;
type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
```

In this I'm using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to split `T` up into its union members, operate on each member, and unite them back together.

`AllKeys<T>` is a conditional type that takes a union type `T` and returns the full set of keys for all members.  So `AllKeys<{a: string} | {b: number}>` is `"a" | "b"`.  Then this is given as a default second argument to `OmitSuperfluousProperties<T, K>`.  For each member of `T`, we intersect it with `Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>>`.  In the case where `T` is `{a: string} | {b: number}` and `K` is `"a" | "b"`, this becomes `{a: string} & {b?: never}` for the first member and `{b: number} & {a?: never}` for the second member.  And finally I use a [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) trick to turn the intersections into single object types, so `{a: string} & {b?: never}` becomes the equivalent and easier-to-look-at `{a: string, b?: never}`.

---

Let's try it:

```
type StrictLocation = OmitSuperfluousProperties<Location>

/* type StrictLocation = {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
    lng?: undefined;
    lat?: undefined;
} | {
    latitude: number;
    lng: number;
    longitude?: undefined;
    lat?: undefined;
} | {
    lat: number;
    longitude: number;
    latitude?: undefined;
    lng?: undefined;
} | {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
    latitude?: undefined;
    longitude?: undefined;
} */
```

That looks like the type you want, right?  We can check:

```
formatLocation({
    lat: 123.456,
    longitude: -12.3456
}); // okay

formatLocation({
    lat: 123.456,
    latitude: 123.456,
    longitude: -12.3456
}); // error! 
/* Argument of type '{ lat: number; latitude: number; longitude: number; }'
 is not assignable to parameter of type 
 '{ latitude: number; longitude: number; lng?: undefined; lat?: undefined; } | 
 { latitude: number; lng: number; longitude?: undefined; lat?: undefined; } | 
 { lat: number; longitude: number; latitude?: undefined; lng?: undefined; } | 
 { ...; }'. */
```

Good news: you get an error in the case where you specify both `latitude` and `lat`.  Bad news: the error is not particularly enlightening if you don't already know what you're looking for.  The compiler sees that the value passed in is not assignable to any of the four members of the union, but it doesn't really know which failure is the important one to tell you about.  A human being would say "you can't use both `latitude` and `lat` here", but the compiler says "you left out `lng` maybe"?  And if you add `lng` then it says "oh, wait, one of these should be `undefined`, I think", which is closer to helpful, but still sub-optimal.  Oh well, at least it's a type compatibility error!

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBIlIAuAnjMgDIhkCWZArgCbIC8eSG9TbEAFxJgzMACMIAJyQBfJAB9uvMsNETpcgNxFS5KrQD2wAOb92SLrh7GzLdmrGSZ8pdYynHGlzuKlK1Eg0huiMxpZBfPbIAGRBtuYQvrr+BkgA8mBMAMrM1FIAZhjMhsxQAApShvmM0AA8ACoANEgA0kgQAB5kEMCsUEiV1dKUrRAUEQCCGBhjFFCNAHyLlil6JA0d3b39SCDAEwD8SAAUa+t6m3HlIFKMmHUAShDwhlKsdQCinfDF7HWtFoAa3GhgKSAaixawAgADdpMtznoAJRbHp9AYMYAFTTpJDHawAbXKSCxSBBFDBGQAusJ0sTqXIkGo4dIkaQWfCpL49AFkNNZuMFpCIpsuujdvsjuTQeDNpzpMk-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-WQgA)

Comment: jclalz, you are my hero! Thank you so much for the detailed yet concise response to my admittedly niche/quirky question. I agree with you regarding the usefulness of the error message, however, it will only be me working on the project. Additionally, this is a much more elegant solution than I had initially setup (a helper class to merge parameters based on a templated object that referenced required & aliased names from the incoming object. Which isn't as useful because it had to be implemented in func. body). Your way has the advantage of catching the input well in advance. Thanks! :)